# How to give only "Go To control panel" permission for a custom role?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I created a custom regular role and given "Go to Control Panel" permission comes in General category. But the "Go To" option is not visible for the user belongs to that particular role. I don't want to give "Add" and "Manage" permission in dock bar for my custom role. What permission extra should I give for my custom role to allow the users belongs to that role to Go To Control Panel?

[image: this is what I needed for my user belongs to my custom role.]

Comment: I think (guess) the user should also have permission for atleast one portlet in Control panel, so that a link can be made to show something in Control panel.

Comment: Yes, Given. Now it is working fine. Thanx.

Comment: Gr8! so converting my comment into an answer for this question for better visibility.

Comment: I gave some more permission for my Custom role. Now "Manage-->Site Content" option is coming there... How can I hide that too...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (guess) the user should also have permission for atleast one portlet in Control panel, so that a link can be made to show something in Control panel.

Since if the User has no access to any of the portlet in Control Panel, there would be no use to go to the Control Panel.